# AngularJS Include Refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have a html page which I am including as follows.

```
<ng-include src="lowerTabURL"></ng-include>
```

This page contains a devextreme control which loads a datasource via ajax.

html:

```
<div class="tab-container" style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <div dx-tabs="lowerTabOptions" dx-item-alias="lowerTab">
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
DemoApp.controller('NavigationController', function DemoController($scope, $templateCache) {
$scope.lowerTabURL = "LowerPanelTest";

$scope.currentSidebarId = 10100;

$scope.lowerTabOptions = {
    dataSource: new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
        load: function (loadTabOptions) {
            console.log('get tabs');

            var d = $.Deferred();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'GetLowerTabs',
                data: { currentSidebarId: $scope.currentSidebarId },
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) { console.log(result); d.resolve(result); }
            });

            return d.promise();
        }
    }),
    animationEnabled: true,
    swipeEnabled: true,
    itemTitleTemplate: 'title',
    height: '100%'
};


$scope.navBarClicked = function (sidebarId) {
    console.log(sidebarId);
    $scope.currentSidebarId = sidebarId;
}
});
```

This works correctly however I have a navbar which when clicked, should change the tab control.

Currently I am changing the sidebarId which gets passed to the ajax call but I need a way to reload the include page so that this is called again. I have tried changing the lowerTabUrl and then changing it back again but this doesnt refresh the page. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your angular version, you will need to watch after changes of value for param sidebarId, @ angular 1 this is achieved by scope.watch

```
scope.$watch('sidebarId', function(newValue, oldValue) {
   // ..call refresh here 
});
```

at angular 1.5 and later you can override ngOnChages

```
this.$onChanges = function (changesObj) {
    if (changesObj.sidebarId) {
      // changesObj.sidebarId.currentValue
    }
  };
```